# Updating a Bokeh figure within an infinite loop instead of plotting an infinite number of figures

Tags: python, infinite-loop, bokeh

I'm trying to plot a stream of sound. I have defined the variable total_data as an array of fixed length and then I update it with each loop using indexing. I had tried `show(p)` within my loop but this kept opening new tabs on my browser. I'm trying to update the figure each loop instead of creating a new one.
Any advice will be highly appreciated and any ideas on a more efficient manner to do this.
Here is a copy of my code:

```
#imports
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

#defining required parameters
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
MAX_PLOT_SIZE = CHUNK * 6
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "VR_11.wav"

#create a variable of the class pyaudio
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

#allow user to choose which input to use
chosen_index=input('Insert index of required device:')
print('')
chosen_device=audio.get_device_info_by_index(int(chosen_index))
print('Chosen device is:', chosen_device)

# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE, input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,input_device_index=int(chosen_index))
print("recording...")

#create fixed length array
total_data=np.zeros(MAX_PLOT_SIZE,dtype=np.int16)
output_file("VR_11.html")
x=np.linspace(0,MAX_PLOT_SIZE,MAX_PLOT_SIZE)

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(title="Live Voltage Plot", x_axis_label='', y_axis_label='Voltage 
Amplitude')


while True:
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    data_sample = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)
    total_data[:(-CHUNK)] = total_data[CHUNK:]
    total_data[-CHUNK:] = data_sample
    p.line(x, total_data, legend="Sound Live Plot",line_color="navy", 
    line_width=2)
    #p.show()- hashed to stop infinite plots from showing up
# stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1):

`show` will always open new tabs or browser windows, that is its express purpose. If you want to keep a single page open and updating, there are basically only a few options:

- You can create and deploy a [Bokeh Server application](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html). The fact that you are using `stream` already points to this—`stream` only works in the context of a Bokeh server application. You can see an example streaming app here: [Streaming OHLC demo](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/ohlc). You would run this app locally by executing

  ```
  bokeh serve ohlc
  ```

  You can optionally add the `--show` argument to have a browser window open directly to the app when the server starts. Important to note: you would ***not use an infinite loop*** in this case. You would need to set up a periodic callback, as shown in that example.
- If the data you want to use to update your plot is available through a REST API that you can periodically poll, you could use an [`AjaxDataSource`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html#bokeh.models.sources.AjaxDataSource). This would allow you to create a standalone HTML document (i.e. not a Bokeh server app) that updates continuously. You can see an example of using it here: [`ajax_source.py`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/ajax_source.py). This one you would run as a standard python script to generate the HTML file:

  ```
  python ajax_source.py
  ```

  There's no infinite loop in Python in this case.  As soon as you view the HTML file in a browser the JavaScript code in it will start pulling data from the REST endpoint you configure at the interval you configure.
- More recently, there is also now a `ServerSentDataSource` which is like a "push" version of an `AjaxDataSource`.
- If you want to run an infinite loop in your own process as you are doing above, you can call `save` instead of `show` to save an HTML file to disk. Or you an use one of the embedding functions in [`bokeh.embed`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html) to generate embedding output. Either way, you'll have to come up with some other way to get the page to refresh periodically (the ways that Bokeh can make content update automatically are described above).